# How to join data in two variables

Tags: laravel

`$orders_details` and `$orders` have data from models. I am trying to join both using a common primary key (id). This is what I have tried,

```
    $orders_details = OrderDetails::
    where('SKU','LIKE','ROUTEINS%')
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
    // order
    $orders = Order::limit(10)
    ->get();
    // return
    $merged = $orders_details->merge($orders);
```

The page stops loading when I do so

Comment: why don't you make use of eloquent model relationships?

Comment: do u means merge all the records in one table, or join two records to one record? or can u post the example that u expect?

Comment: Do you mean concat the **Order** record that has matching **OrderDetail** record?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Laravel Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships) for this.

If your OrderDetails Table has a `order_id` column that references the order:

```
class Order extends Model {
    public function OrderDetail() {
        return $this->hasOne(OrderDetail::class);
    }
}

class OrderDetail extends Model {
   public function Order() {
       return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
   }
}
```

Than you can get your order details with the corosponding order like this:

```
$orders_details = OrderDetails::
    where('SKU','LIKE','ROUTEINS%')
    ->limit(10)
    ->with('order')
    ->get();
```

Comment: or use inner join if using DB facade